# What is a short phrase to express the will to always progress in life?

Tags: traduction

I am writing a story (in English) were I want the main protagonist to have a certain phrase tattooed. I can translate it easily with an online translator, but I want to avoid being too literal or too grammatically complex.

Quite often such motivational and inspirational words/phrases make (heavy) use of colloquialism, which, in my opinion, is difficult to get from standard online translators.

I am describing the phrase below in English, with an English example and my researched French solution:

1. a phrase that expresses the will to always progress in life, e.g.
   "always forward" or "forwards" - "en avant"

Is this an appropriate translation for the intended purpose? If not, is there a better solution?

Edit: I edited the question to focus on one problem only.

Comment: It looks like you are asking three different questions at once.

Comment: Hello, I do not understand, if you write your story in English, why do you want to translate it into French ? Anyway, for your translation (many questions in the same publication) may be try HiNative or Speakwiz. :)

Comment: @Oreste: The protagonist has French tattoos because he is French ;) Thanks for the alternatives, I'll take a look at them.

Comment: Buzz lightyear style: "Vers l'infini et au-delà". Or something maybe more poetic : "Meilleur qu'hier, moins bon que demain" (not an idiomatic expression as such, but not unheard neither)

Comment: For inspiration, you could look up this list of military slogans: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_devises_militaires_fran%C3%A7aises . "Toujours avant" (and variations), "Fonce devant, fais ce que dois", etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Toujours de l'avant.
2. Ne pas baisser les bras.